# Can pyright load stubs for global definitions?

Tags: python, python-typing, pyright

I have a python file that gets run in a customized way via a loader, such that it has additional global functions such as `BoolVariable` and classes such as `Environment` available.

I'd like to create stub type declarations for these so my pyright isn't cluttered with undefined warnings. Can pyright load a `.pyi` that's not tied to any particular module so I can define stubs for these top-level symbols?

Comment: I'd suggest using custom `typeshedPath`. Clone the repo (and setup CI to maintain it consistent with default one), add your desired stub file, and import everything needed from it into [`builtins`](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/master/stdlib/builtins.pyi) (maybe like `from mystub import BoolVariable as BoolVariable`). I'm not sure that it works, but looks promising.

Comment: UPD: that was right feeling, I found [a reference](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/9802) proving it's possible.